# Advice - Forms and Credit Card Security

Tags: forms, security

I'm working on a website for a client where he wants a order form created and e-mailed back to him.  Because of the nature of the business, the card cannot be charged until the order is verified that all the items are in stock and the shipping cost verified - then they charge the card themselves.  So the form is supposed to gather the card numbers.  The problem is that when I use a webform, it actually SAVES the credit card number!  YIKES!! I've created a PDF interactive form, which I think is a much better and safer option, but I can't get the PDF to display on the page like the customer wants.
Does anyone have any advice on what I should do or look into??
Thanks so much!!

Comment: It's illegal to store the information without PCI compliance. And storing them in Webform_submissions will never comply with it.

Comment: You could try to discuss with the client to ask customer to agree for a Paypal payment agreement (1and1 does this) so your client can charge the card only when necessary without the customer presence at that time.

Comment: Ayesh K - does that mean that for each of his customers he'd have to send an agreement?

Comment: Yes. But just once for the customer and it seems like a legit case to use that kind of agreement. You don;t have to store the credit card info - just charge it when you need.

Comment: Also remember that you are the web developer and the customer is not, so it is partly your role to educate the client that this is not a good idea (to put it mildly). For example if I ask my mechanic to fill my gas tank up with water they would likely say no, that's crazy.
If it was me, in this case, I would tell the client they should do it the right way or I'm not doing it. Although if you are not in the position where you can turn a client away then you have a dilemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not secure at all to store or send credit card numbers in the database and via plain text email. Without careful consideration bad practice to do so.

I think you need to rethink the order fulfilment process.

You should instead consider using the refund feature of your payment gateway to refund payment after the transaction is completed, if it fails validation.

Alternatively, look at providing some sort of API process so the stock and shipping details can be verified during the checkout process, prior to payment.

There's also an option of "Authorize" vs "Capture" payment modes provided by some payment gateways to allow delayed payment capture.

In the meantime, please review PCI Compliance requirements:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard
- https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/why_comply.php
- https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_ssc_quick_guide.pdf

Comment: Hi David - This will not work for the client at all.  I've tried to talk them into this, explaining that it is not secure but it's the way they've always done it in the past through their old website without any issues. Do you think there's any way to encrypt something somewhere?  UGGGGggggg... I'm not sure what to do with this!!

Comment: Regardless of what the client says now, you can bet if something goes wrong and they get in trouble they will pass the responsibility (and perhaps lawsuit) to you.

Comment: I agree!!  With his workflow though, using a pay up front approach really doesn't work at all - it's plants, so there are constantly out of stock - out of season and substitutions, so the only way I can think of is for him to personally call each client order to get their payment information once the order is finalized.

Comment: They might be interested in reading about PCI Compliance, e.g: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard#Requirements

Comment: Do you think that there is a payment gateway that will "hold" the order and allow for changes and substitutions until the store owner finally chooses to charge the client?

Comment: Other than trying to get the point across that it's risky, I don't fully understand why you would say that it's "not secure at all" to store the number in the database. There are obviously systems that do store the credit card number in the database, they just encrypt it and do a lot of things to lock down the server.

Comment: @greggles, sure but those "secure" companies will be PCI compliant.

Comment: @everaftergraphics many payment gateways provide "Authorize" and "Capture" payment modes with Authorize mode payments able to be cancelled or captured at a later date. e.g https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!  Thank you David!!!!!!  I obviously missed the significance of that when you first commented above!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, saving plain text credit card details to your website is absolutely out of the question.

Also, emailing credit card details is out of the question.

Just don't do it ever.

It would help to know what payment gateway you are to be using because then we could give advice based on their API.

For example, in Australia I almost exclusively use eWay.

Now eWay has what they call stored payments, which is where you send them the transaction, which is stored with them securely and not processed until you send them an approval.

So in this case the checkout process would create a stored payment and then at a later date, the customer or your admin can approve it, which actually charges the credit card.

For reference you can see the eWay info pages on this:

- [Stored payments (XML)](http://www.eway.com.au/developers/api/stored-%28xml%29)
- [Stored payments (Shared)](http://www.eway.com.au/developers/api/stored-%28shared%29)

Most reputable payment gateways should have an equivalent service.

Then it is just down to whether or not there is a drupal module already out there that integrates with the specific API you require. If not you will have to either make one that fits with your e commerce setup or make a custom module that doesn't integrate with something else (like ubercart or commerce) but just communicates with the gateway as required.

Comment: He has declined using a payment gateway.  It will not work for his orders since there are too many "out of stock" "out of season" and substitutions.  He would rather take the order and work with the customer to fulfill the order. I agree it's not safe, what I'm looking for is any other way to do this outside of a payment gateway.  I wasn't sure if there was a payment gateway that would hold the order and allow changes until the retailer finally says ok - the order is good to be charged.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely payment gateways that allow for that as mentioned above. Most good gateways should have such a feature.
There are definitely other ways to do it, like just plainly storing the data, or encrypting the data (you could borrow some encryption code from another ecommerce module that does such things), but you open yourself up to potential trouble down the line, along with the ethical dilemma of not telling customers who use the site that their credit card details are being stored insecurely (if that is the case).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to store or email the credit card number (or PAN as its often called) if you encrypt it in some way.

The fundamental problem is a mix of what is secure and PCI compliance. It's not a matter of what's "legal or illegal" but what terms of the contract are with the merchant gateway. Storing the PAN may break those terms.

What is your plan for the store to become PCI compliant? If you don't have a plan, you'll need to get one :) The plan is likely "hire someone to do a review and then implement any advice from the review." I suggest getting in touch with whomever you plan to do the review and ask them if storing the PAN will be OK if you encrypt it. I suggest the [Encrypt module](http://drupal.org/project/encrypt) if you do find out that's OK.

If the client refuses to spend money on PCI compliance then you have to ask what risk you're willing to accept as the site builder. If you do store the PAN or send it in an email you won't be the first programmer to do it. It's risky and probably not a good idea, but...if you do go ahead with it I suggest writing a physical letter to your client advising them of the risks and why they shouldn't do it and getting them to sign the letter. On a related note: do you have a general commercial insurance policy? :)

Comment: I can guarantee he won't spend money on PCI compliance.  As of last night my advice to him was to take the orders online and then anyone who chooses to pay by credit card - deal with the final details and payment over the phone or in person.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate the time you took to share your knowledge!!  And I'm definitely going to have to look into some sort of professional insurance!!

Comment: In addition to what could happen to you in legal terms, there is also a moral dilemma in regards to the people who use the website assuming that their details are being handled securely. It is their details that are also at risk without their knowing.